# MeteorJS - How to record sound from phone mic?

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, audio

I was able to get sound byte data from the browser, but when I build it for the phone and try it out it doesn't work.

I have checked around and people had luck with `cordova-plugin-media-capture` however, it seems to record audio and archive it on the device.

I need to somehow get the audio data and manipulate it myself on the phone.

What I am currently doing to get audio on a non-mobile device

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(onMediaSuccess).catch(onMediaError);

function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'audio/wav';
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
    mediaRecorder.start();

    function handleDataAvailable(blob) {
        toBuffer(blob, function(err, buffer) {
            if (err)
                throw err

            ws.publish(`com.app.audioStream__`, {payload: buffer});
        });
    }
}
```

However, it seems get user media is having no effect.

I have tried using `navigator.device.capture.captureAudio`, but it is slightly difficult to debug it on my phone and see what the console outputs.

When I do use the method though, it prompts some UI managed by cordova that wants me to rec a sound and stop it then writes it to a file. I am looking for actively reading the mic.

Edit:
I have even tried with `cordova-diagnostic-plugin`

```
    // check and request microphone access
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getMicrophoneAuthorizationStatus(function(status) {
        if (status !== "GRANTED") {
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestMicrophoneAuthorization(function(status) {
                //...
                return;
            });
        }
    }, function() {
        throw new Meteor.error('failed to get permission for microphone');
    });
```

which results in a blank screen.

SO far there has been no easy way for me to prompt mic permissions.

Comment: Are you 1) Declaring sound permission in mobile-config.js and 2) requesting the permission at run time?

Comment: @Mikkel I don't believe I did either. It only prompts for access to media, but not specifically microphone. [mobile config](https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html) has no info on any sound specific permissions. How would I set the permissions and request permission to mic?

Comment: looking around the `AndroidManifest.xml` I found `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`